# Qué significa "el puente" en "estoy en casa para el puente de Todos los Santos"

Tags: definiciones

El contexto:

> El sábado siguiente, en efecto, estoy en casa para el puente de Todos
>   los Santos.

Si yo fuera dar palos de ciego sin fuentes concreto, diría que tiene una semejanza a "faire le pont" de francés que he leido para significar añadir un día de ñapa entre dos períodos de vacación.

Voy a ganar el premio planta rodadora esta semana con mis preguntas. Es un premio por preguntas en Stack Exchange pocas valoradas y pocas vistas sin ninguna respuesta. ¡Yay!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí, un puente es cuando tienes algún día festivo durante la semana y además de este, por ejemplo, jueves, también tienes el viernes, así dándote cuatro días en seguida de vacaciones (porque hacen un puente que liga el día festivo con el fin de semana)

Eso dicho, últimamente es frecuente escuchar puente para referir a incluso para cuando un día festivo que cae en algún viernes o lunes (así tres días libres) a pesar de que no hay ningún puente metafórico.

Comment: El viento sopla en un desierto desolado y remoto occupado solo por mis  otras preguntas. Voy a ganar el premio con una.

Comment: La banda sonora de "The good, bad and ugly" sigue...

Comment: En Chile es simplemente un "fin de semana largo" (aburrida forma de decirlo). Al día lunes o viernes que queda encerrado le decimos "sándwich".

Answer (score 2):

Completando la respuesta de guifa:

- Si se trata de varios dias festivos seguidos, a menudo se habla de un **macropuente**.
- Si se unen varios festivos no consecutivos, a menudo se denomina **acueducto**.

Answer (score 2):

En Colombia la gran mayoría de los días festivos no se "celebran" en la fecha exacta sino el lunes siguiente y por esto casi todos los festivos generan que el fin de semana se alargue. Eso es lo que aquí llamamos **puente**: un fin de semana de 3 días.

Para este año (2017) el día de todos los santos que en general se celebra el 1<sup>o</sup> de noviembre, el día festivo será el 6 de noviembre que corresponde al lunes siguiente al 01/11/2017, por lo tanto **el puente de Todos los Santos** son los dias 4,5 y 6 de noviembre.

Esto no pasa en todos los países todos los años pero la ley colombiana hace que en Colombia **siempre** haya un puente de Todos los Santos cada año.